# How to cancel ANTLR project in Ecilpse

Tags: eclipse, antlr3

I selected my eclipse project as a ANTLR project.(I am using ANTLR IDE plug-in for eclipse)

But I don't know how to cancel it.

Auto code generation is really bothering me. This is the reason I want to dis-select.

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* want to disable automatic generation from the Antlr grammar, go to project properties (in the popup menu of the project in the Package/Project Explorer), and go to the Builders tab, and remove the Antlr builder.

But be vary, this could cause some unwanted side-effects, depending on what the Antlr IDE expects from the builder.